# How do we calculate a monthly average value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, redash

I have a list of documents in Mongo, each containing the value of a metric for a service for that day. The scheme is as follows:

```
    _id: ObjectId("..."),
    name: '<some_metric_name>',
    service: '<service_name>',
    timestamp_unix: Long("1635033600000"),
    timestamp: '2021-10-24 03:00:00 +0300 EEST',
    value: 99.9810785241248
  },
```

I would like to have a dashboard in Redash where I can see the calculated average of these values per month, grouped by service.

e.g. over a span of 4 months it should look like this:

```
| service       | date                     | avg
| my_svc        | 01-01-2022 to 31-01-2022 | 99.500
| my_svc        | 01-02-2022 to 28-02-2022 | 99.100
| my_svc        | 01-03-2022 to 31-03-2022 | 99.400
| my_svc        | 01-04-2022 to 30-04-2022 | 99.900
| my_svc_total  | 01-01-2022 to 30-04-2022 | 99.475
| my_svc_2      | 01-01-2022 to 31-01-2022 | 99.150
.
.
.
```

So I need a query that is going to aggregate the documents by month, calculate the average and group them by month and service. So far I have this that can calculate the overall average:

```
{
    "collection": "metrics",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                        "date": {
                            "$toDate": "$timestamp_unix"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "total_average": {
                    "$avg": "$value"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your data group by month+year and service. So you should put both condition in your group stage. Then, you can get the average with the accumulator as you did.

```
{
    "collection": "metrics",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "service" : "$service",
                    "month" : 
                        { "$dateToString": {
                            "format": "%Y-%m",
                            "date": {
                                "$toDate": "$timestamp_unix"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "average": {
                    "$avg": "$value"
                }
            }
        },
        { "$project" : 
            {"service" : "$_id.service",
             "year-month":"$_id.month", 
             "average":1, 
             "_id":0
            }
        },
        { "$sort": {"service" : 1, "year-month" : 1} }
    ]
}
```

This should give you data you want.

If you also want the total average per service, i would suggest to do use a $facet stage and do the exact same group stage but without the date condition.

Comment: Instead of `$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m", ...}` you can also use [$dateTrunc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) - this also considers time zone

Comment: @Fourchette It works! just one issue, the services appear scrambled in the list. How can we ensure all of the same services are grouped together and sorted by date?

Comment: Just add a $sort stage after the $project one, i edited my answer !
Then you can replace 1 by -1 if it's sorted in bad order.